# how to filter array list of collection view which is in accessory view

Tags: ios, swift

//  I just want to filter array list which is shown in collection view cell when user enter text in the textfield.
    On textfield editing collection data will be sort and filter according to textfield input. In case of collection view has a data about states, If I input 'A' in textfield, all collection data will be sort and display all state names starting with alphabet 'A'. Please tell me logic for this.

ios iphone

here is the link of my project ---- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d56PWO2j6YcDU2AJyCseZC16dfUeV7Bd?usp=sharing //

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CustomView {
            self.textField.inputAccessoryView = customView
        }
    }
}

class CustomView: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let words = ["abscind","downwind","headwind","lind","rescind","sind","skinned","tailwind","thin-skinned","tinned","twinned","upwind","whirlwind","wind"]

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.words.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.label.text = self.words[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: Please provide code that you have used to try and solve the problem with, and both your input and desired output.

Comment: You project contains no storyboard add and send us the code

Comment: class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CustomView {
            self.textField.inputAccessoryView = customView
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another array `filteredWords` in `CustomView` class and use that array in collection view datasource methods

```
class CustomView: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let words = ["abscind","downwind","headwind","lind","rescind","sind","skinned","tailwind","thin-skinned","tinned","twinned","upwind","whirlwind","wind"]
    var filteredWords = [String]()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        filteredWords = words
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.filteredWords.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.label.text = self.filteredWords[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

In `ViewController` add target to `textField` for `.editingChanged`.
Then `filter`, `sort` the array and reload the `collectionView`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? CustomView {
            self.textField.inputAccessoryView = customView
            self.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        }
    }
    @objc func textChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if let customView = textField.inputAccessoryView as? CustomView {
            if textField.text!.isEmpty {
                customView.filteredWords = customView.words
                customView.collectionView.reloadData()
            } else {
                customView.filteredWords = customView.words
                    .filter({ $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(textField.text!) }).sorted(by: {
                        if let range0 = $0.range(of: textField.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive], range: $0.startIndex..<$0.endIndex, locale: nil),
                            let range1 = $1.range(of: textField.text!, options: [.caseInsensitive], range: $1.startIndex..<$1.endIndex, locale: nil) {
                            return range0.lowerBound < range1.lowerBound
                        } else {
                            return false
                        }
                    })
                customView.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The sorted array will be sorted based on the index of searched text. Ex. for text `"in"` the filtered and sorted result will be

> ["l**in**d", "s**in**d", "t**in**ned", "w**in**d", "sk**in**ned", "th**in**-skinned",
>   "tw**in**ned", "upw**in**d", "absc**in**d", "resc**in**d", "downw**in**d", "headwind",
>   "tailw**in**d", "whirlw**in**d"]

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `dataSource` everytime there is a change in `textField's` `text`.

You can track the changes in `textField's text` using `UITextFieldDelegate` method - `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`

I've taken 2 arrays:

**1.** `arr`: It will contain the whole content that you can show in `collectionView`

**2.** `dataSourceArr`: It will contain the `filtered content` from `arr` based on `textField's text`. Initially both the `arrays` will have same content.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var arr = [String]() //Original Array
    var dataSourceArr = arr //Filtered array based on textField content

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSourceArr.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        self.reload(textField)
        return true
    }

    func reload(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let text = textField.text {
            dataSourceArr = self.arr.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(text) }).sorted()
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have updated my code .. i have a accessory view in Xib

Answer (score 0):

You should not suppose to ask question like this, you should also provide the code that you have tried

```
let array = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "Aalborg", "Indiana", "New Jersey"]
let searchtext = "A"

let filterArray = array.filter({ $0.hasPrefix(searchtext) }).sorted()
```